# Thread-safe access to the same variable from different flows (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, thread-safety, coroutine, kotlin-flow

Is this code thread safe? Do I need a synchronized block or something like that? source1 and source2 endless Kotlin Flow

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    var listAll = mutableListOf<String>()
    var list1 = mutableListOf<String>()
    var list2 = mutableListOf<String>()

    launch {
        source1.getNames().collect { list ->
            list1 = list

            listAll = mutableListOf()
            listAll.addAll(list1)
            listAll.addAll(list2)

            //then consume listAll as StateFlow or return another flow with emit(listAll)
        }
    }

    launch {
        source2.getNames().collect { list ->
            list2 = list

            listAll = mutableListOf()
            listAll.addAll(list2)
            listAll.addAll(list1)

            //then consume listAll as StateFlow or return another flow with emit(listAll)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `scope.launch` when you are already in `viewModelScope`. What is `scope`? Why do you need `MutableList` instead of just `List`?

Comment: Because I want to change the same list (not necessarily a list, any variable) from different flows.  And the question is, is this approach thread-safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is not thread safe.

However, it is called from `viewModelScope.launch` which runs on `Dispatchers.Main` by default. So your inner `launch` blocks will be called sequentially. This means that after all you will get the result which is produced by second `launch` block.

To achieve asynchronous behavior, you want to use `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default)`.
Your code will probably fire concurrent modification exception in that case.

To synchronize it, you may want to use Java's `Collections.synchronizedList` which blocks the list while one thread is performing operations with it, so the other thread are not able to perform modifications.

Or perform synchronizing manually using `Mutex`.

```
 val mutex = Mutex()  

 viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {       

     launch {
         mutex.withLock {
             ... // Your code 
         }    
     }

     launch {
         mutex.withLock {
             ... // Your code 
         }    
     }
 }
```

Read [official Kotlin guide to shared mutable state](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/shared-mutable-state-and-concurrency.html)

After all, I am struggling to imagine real life example in which you will actually use that code. You probably don't need asynchronous behavior, you will be fine without using two launch blocks. Or you should rethink your design to avoid need of manual synchronization of two coroutines.

Comment: Although not relevant to this question, how would you do this example:


`val user1 = db.collection("names").whereEqualTo("user1", "ALEX").snapshots()
        val user2 = db.collection("names").whereEqualTo("user2", "ALEX").snapshots()`
  

In firestore there is no way to apply a logical OR, so you have to use several queries, and then the question arises how to combine them. I think the above code is suitable for merging, why not, what approach would you take? Using kotlin(merge, combine or zip) is not suitable as each query is independent of the other